# Cleaning up memory after using EKEvent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Was looking at some code and it looks to be leaking memory. And I'm not sure should I clean this up? Or is it ok?

```
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
```

I would have guessed this is an autorelease since its a connivence method.

But when i read

```
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

I see an alloc and an init, so I get nervous about wondering will it be leaking.

Full block of code below:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = @"Test Event for Code Demo";

event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 

[eventStore release];
```

Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the properties startDate and endDate need to be alloc'd and init'd. You are creating an autoreleased object with your current code.

```
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore]; // autoreleased this way
```

To fill your dates and properties, try an alternate method to fill.

```
event.startDate = [NSDate date];
event.endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];
```

Now you just need to release eventStore like you are currently doing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EKEventViewController, Apple documentation says following:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) EKEvent *event
Discussion
This property must be set before the view is displayed.
```

[EKEventViewController Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)